# jQuery que troque background de div especifica

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Preciso de uma ajuda com o seguinte problema, tenho o seguinte HTML, que faz parte de um acordion

```
 <div id="accordion2"> 

<h3 class="btn-sub-main"><a>Banho</a><div class="seta-btn-sub"></div></h3>
    <div id="outraDiv">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">condicionadores</a><span></span></li>
            <li><a href="#">sabonetes</a><span></span></li>
            <li><a href="#">shampoos</a><span></span></li>
            <li><a href="#">outros</a><span></span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<h3 class="btn-sub-main"><a>Higiene Infantil</a><div class="seta-btn-sub"></div></h3>
    <div id="outraDiv"> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">condicionadores</a><span></span></li>
            <li><a href="#">sabonetes</a><span></span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<h3 class="btn-sub-main"><a>Alimentação</a><div class="seta-btn-sub"></div></h3>
    <div id="outraDiv"> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">condicionadores</a><span></span></li>
            <li><a href="#">outros</a><span></span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Tenho o seguinte código Javascript que altera o fundo da DIV="seta-btn-sub" (imagem de seta):

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion2").accordion({
        icons: null,
        beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#" + ui.newHeader.attr("id")).children(".seta-btn-sub").toggleClass("active");
            $("#" + ui.oldHeader.attr("id")).children(".seta-btn-sub").toggleClass("active");
        },
        create: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#" + ui.header.attr("id")).children(".seta-btn-sub").toggleClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

Tentei de diversas formas fazer o que desejo baseado neste código, mas não consegui.
Desejo que o h3 que tem a class "btn-sub-main" troque a cor do background quando o campo **aria-hidden')=='true** , ou que add uma class e por lá insiro as característica do CSS que desejo.

Abaixo outro script que existe neste accordion que me esconde/mostra a **div="outraDiv"**, tentei usa-la juntando as duas de diversas formas mas não consegui.

```
controlaOutraDiv = function(selector){
    $("#accordion2 h3", selector).bind('click',function(){
        console.log($(this).next().attr('aria-hidden'));
        if($(this).next().attr('aria-hidden')=='true'){
            $("#outraDiv ul li").show();
           }else if($(this).next().attr('aria-hidden')=='false'){
            $("#outraDiv ul li").hide();

        }
    });
}
```

Código do efeito do accordion:

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion2").accordion({
        collapsible: true
    });
    controlaOutraDiv("#accordion2");
});
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mx2BQ/)

Comment: Dá para adicionar mais código aqui para ter um exemplo melhor do seu problema? http://jsfiddle.net/XQdc3/

Comment: Veja se melhorou um pouco amigo, este é todo o código JS que tenho referente ao accordion2 e inseri mais um pouco do html, já mostrando 2 tabelas do accordion2.

Comment: Antes de postar minha resposta vai uma dica: em uma mesma página [tag:html] não coloque 2 elementos com um mesmo `id` assim como ver com `<div id="outraDiv">` se precisar de vários elementos com a mesma identificação use classes assim `<div class="outraDiv">`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O próprio accordion já atribui uma classe ao elemento que está aberto, assim pode usar `.ui-state-active` para alcançar a div aberta. Note que o plugin usa uma `background-image` que precisa desabilitar se quiser usar o background.

[**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/S2Nr4/)

```
h3.ui-state-active {
    background-color: #ccf;
    background-image: none;
}
```

Em relação à segunda parte da sua pergunta onde quer esconder os `#outraDiv ul li` penso que a resposta é também CSS.

Note que ID's duplicadas são HTML inválido e que isso causa quebras no código. Assim corrija no HTML `id="outraDiv"` para `class="outraDiv"` e teste este selector CSS em vez de jQuery:

```
h3.ui-state-active .outraDiv ul li{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a [API do jQuery-ui accordion](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion) existe um evento chamado [beforeActivate](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-beforeActivate).

Este evento possui dois parâmetros `event` e `ui` onde:

- `event` - Representa o tipo de evento que está sendo chamado, no caso é o `beforeActivate`
- `ui` - Representa os elementos que este evento manipula

> - **ui**
>   Type: [Object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Object)
>
>   - **newHeader**
>     Type: [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery)
>     The header that is about to be activated.(O cabeçalho que está prestes a ser ativado)
>   - **oldHeader**
>     Type: [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery)
>     The header that is about to be deactivated. (O cabeçalho que está prestes a ser desativado)
>   - **newPanel**
>     Type: [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery)
>     The panel that is about to be activated.(O conteúdo que está prestes a ser desativado)
>   - **oldPanel**
>     Type: [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery)
>     The panel that is about to be deactivated.(O conteúdo que está prestes a ser desativado)

Desta forma assim como você utiliza `ui.newHeader.attr("id")` e `ui.oldHeader.attr("id")` para pegar os ids do cabeçalho que acabou de ser ativado e do cabeçalho que acabou de ser desativado respectivamente, você pode utilizar `ui.newPanel.attr("id")` e `ui.oldPanel.attr("id")` para para pegar os ids do conteúdo que acabou de ser ativado e do conteúdo que acabou de ser desativado respectivamente.

Dessa forma para trocar o background destes elementos você precisa utilizar `ui.newPanel.attr("algum_atributo")` ou `ui.oldPanel.attr("algum_atributo")` para pegar os atributos dos *Panels*.

Outra forma até mais simples de utilizar é fazer uso das classes que o próprio [jquery-ui](/questions/tagged/jquery-ui) utiliza para definir qual *header* e *panel* estão ativos no momento.

São elas:

- `.ui-accordion-header-active` - é usada no cabeçalho que está ativo
- `.ui-accordion-content-active` - é usada no conteúdo que está ativo